# Authentication in a Play server without browser

Tags: java, android, security, cookies, playframework-2.3

So, I have an Android app which means I'm not using a browser (I'll explain why this is important in few lines) and I wish to use Security.Authenticator with Play! 2.3.8 
 
Basically, Play uses the current session (which is directly related to the browser), check what's in there by using `String getUserame(Context ctx)` and send back the username if this one exist. If not, then it returns a `HTTP redirect` using `Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx)` 
 
Here is my problem: I use Play as a server for remote apps. How can I use Play's authentication provided methods with my app? It's tricky because of course, I can't store something in session due to the fact I'm not using any browser.

Do you guys have some workaround or solutions for this?

Comment: That's the default behavior of `Authenticator`. You can easily override the `getUsername` method and detect if your user is authenticated in the headers of the request or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Play uses the current session (which is directly related to the browser)...
>   I can't store something in session due to the fact I'm not using any
>   browser.

The above is false.

You can easily store cookies in the Android's [CookieStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieStore.html) so you can safely use Play's session cookie with it.

Relevant SO questions that will help you figure it out how to do this Android side:

[Android: How to store cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082799/android-how-to-store-cookies)

[Storing and restoring cookies in Android (persistent cookie storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704023/storing-and-restoring-cookies-in-android-persistent-cookie-storage)