# how to save cookies in android app?

Tags: android, api, cookies

API creating and save data in a cookie. It works well on the browser. But that cookie is not saved in the android app. Always show a blank array. Anybody know about this? Do android developer has to add any library to save cookie? or it is API side problem.

Comment: U have to store the cookie in shared preferences and use it for other requests which you want to proceed. By default it won't save

Comment: sharedpreferences is the answer

Comment: Go through with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704023/storing-and-restoring-cookies-in-android-persistent-cookie-storage

Comment: then you save them incorrectly. You need to fix way you save them, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
/**
 * Checks the response headers for session cookie and saves it if it
 * finds it.
 * 
 * @param headers
 * Response Headers.
 */
public void checkSessionCookie(Map<String, String> headers)
{
    // Config.SET_COOKIE_KEY = "Set-Cookie"
    if (headers.containsKey(Config.SET_COOKIE_KEY) && headers.get(Config.SET_COOKIE_KEY).startsWith(Config.SESSION_COOKIE))
    {
        String cookie = headers.get(Config.SET_COOKIE_KEY);
        if (cookie.length() > 0)
        {
            String[] splitCookie = cookie.split(";");
            String[] splitSessionId = splitCookie[0].split("=");
            cookie = splitSessionId[1];
            // Now here set cookie to your Preference file.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly refer,

[#How to store data locally in an Android app!](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

among this options, you can use `#Shared Preferences` and store user information and access it through out the application.