# Storing user data in from api in "session"

Tags: android

I am not sure of the best way to do this, when user logs in my app i want to store his data from an api. I will be using this data trough out the app, so i dont call getUserData all the time . So i want to ask for an opinion

Do i store user data in application context so i can access it in all activites/fragments

**Or**

Do i store the user data in SharedPreferences as json string (User has a lot of small data name,lastname,age,email...)

**Or**

Do i store it in database (Since i only need storing for this i tought this way might be too much, but could be wrong)

**Or**

There might be a better way to do this?

Comment: You should use sharedPreferences.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/46356961/1848157

Comment: User shared preference.

Comment: @Radhey i didn't mean like that i have getUserData method in API and that returns me his data. that is why i said "session" sorry if that made it confusing

Comment: Ok thank you guys, i will store user data in sharedPreferences. I was very unsure about this since it can be done in many ways

Comment: at the end you want to stores user data coming form the API right! you can write user data in to #file or you can use preferences. you have to mange it with flags as per your session and overwrite that data every time.

Comment: @Radhey thank you i didn't think of storing in file. Will try preferences for start thank you

Comment: I create a singleton when the app is launched. It stores cookies in SharedPreferences..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePreferences are great, but it is stored in plain text and can be read by rooted devices. Someone with a stolen rooted phone can potentially access tons of user info.

Use a library like:
https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences

To encrypt the preferences or use a secret key to encrypt and decrypt the data.

You can initialized the user object on the OnCreate of your Application Object this way. Have you app instance be a singleton and you can access this user object object amongst your activities and fragments.

Comment: I just want to thank everyone in comments and you, for helping out. Did not knew preferences are somewhat unsecure, ty for the library